# How to detect or check if one device is being used in Mac Address Spoofing attack?

Tags: spoofing, mac-address

How to detect or check if one device is being used in Mac Address Spoofing attack??

We already check the system... Malwarebytes, Windows AV Scans and nothing is detectec.. also there is any kind of compromised tool/app.

Comment: A MAC spoofing attack is typically done by a device you don't control pretending to be a device you do control.

Comment: you check ARP tables to look for anomalous changes or gratuitous ARP packets in the network traffic

Comment: I already check but nothing occurs...

Comment: Are you asking if a device that you own is changing its MAC address to spoof another device?  Or are you asking if someone is using a device that you do not own is spoofing one of your device.  It sounds like you are asking the former, but the latter is much more common.  If you're asking about the former, you are likely to have some difficulty figuring this out, since if the device is compromised, you may not be able to trust any logs on the host.